# How to output debug statements to console in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, react-native, visual-studio-code, console.log

How do I write to console from a .js method?

`console.log` is not showing anything in Console tab in Visual Studio Code

Here is an example of my method

```
_onPressItem = (index) => {
    console.log("Property Finder >> Pressed row: "+index);
};
```

This is triggered when I press on an item in my ListView.  If I run this through XCode, I will see `console.log` line above printed in XCode.  But if I debug it in VSCode, I see no `console.log` line being printed at all.

My Steps:
1. Open my project in VSCode
My VS Code has installed react-native tools already

2. `Cmd+P` then type command `Debug: Start Debuging` (it is an available command, I just select it)
3. My App starts, DEBUG CONSOLE tab shows some lines but no line from my `console.log` command is shown

Comment: show some actual code.

Comment: Maybe react-native is grabbing the console object? Try assigning the console object to your own var before importing react-native. Just a thought.

Answer (score 10):

I added:

```
"outputCapture": "std"
```

to my debug launch configuration and `console.log` statements work in the "DEBUG CONSOLE" tab.

Alternatively:

```
"console": "integratedTerminal"
```

shows `console.log` in the "TERMINAL" tab.

Answer (score 1):

`Debug > Start Debugging F5` and see the output at `DEBUG CONSOLE`

Comment: still not seeing any console.log statements being output to DEBUG CONSOLE even though I added extension for react-native tools

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue.

I'm opening in a browser ("type": "vscode-edge-devtools.debug") in the configuration.

In the browser, if I hit f12 and go to the 'console' tab, that appears to be where the console.log is writing to.